# CSS grid equal size columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to create 3 divs each containing 1 <p>-tag and distribute all 3 on the same row with an equal width using CSS grid.

Most sources say that I should use `grid-template-columns` to achieve this. Some say to go for `1fr 1fr 1fr`, some say `repeat(3, 1fr)`, and yet more say `repeat(3, auto)`.

The result is the same. The 3 divs end up on the same line, but their widths change depending on the width of their content. Is there a way to force all 3 divs to have the same width and simply use the next line if the content is too wide?

The snippet should show the situation I'm in.

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.content {
    margin: 2em;
}
```

```html
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="content">
            <p>TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTES</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTES</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>TESTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTES</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your grid is fine - the content is the problem here.

You can try `word-break` or `overflow` as a workaround:

`word-break` solution:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  border: 2px dotted green;
}

.content {
  margin: 2em;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.content p {
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTES</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTES</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>TESTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTES</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

`overflow` solution:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  border: 2px dotted green;
}

.content {
  margin: 2em;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTES</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTES</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>TESTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTES</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** Apparently, `word-break: break-word;` does not work in Firefox - thanks, @Yaakov Ainspan. Another reminder that you should test your code in multiple browsers. `word-break: break-all;` can be used instead.

Comment: Fantastic. Both suggestions solve my problem with some subtle differences that I'll have to experiment with. Thank you very much!

The way I phrased the question might make the word-break option more correct, but it actually seems like the overflow solution works best for me in practise.

Answer (score 1):

@fen1x's answer was close, but not quite. I experimented with this a bit, and found that `word-break: break-all` worked, while `break-word` did not. (The overflow solution sort of works, but isn't what the OP asked for).

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.content {
    margin: 2em;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
        <div class="content">
            <p>TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTES</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTES</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>TESTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTES</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Additionally, this solution does not need to be applied to individual elements inside the grid item, but can be applied directly to the item.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
```