# Centering wrapping fixed-width columns with CSS Grid or Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid, centering

Would it be possible to center a wrapping CSS grid with fixed-width grid items inside both a desktop and mobile viewport, using Flexbox or CSS Grid? I am aiming toward a solution without resorting to media queries if possible.

Here is the closest I could get to a solution that still wraps using CSS Grid (based on searches for "CSS grid equal width" and similar queries):

[Codepen snippet - CSS Grid](https://codepen.io/jade-silhouette/pen/WNrpGwj)

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

body {
  margin: 20px;
  place-self: center;
}

nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 180px);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  max-width: 800px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>Link A</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>Link B</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>Link C</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>Link D</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>Link E</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

In addition to the above snippet, I have also tried:

- adding `display: grid` to the `html` tag
- adding `grid-auto-columns: 180px;` and `grid-auto-flow: column;` to the `nav` tag

These additions help center the grid inside the viewport, but cause the wrapping to not function properly.

---

Here is my attempt at a solution using Flexbox (effective, but the list grid doesn't center in viewports smaller than max-width - which I'd desire over the existing left alignment):

[Codepen snippet - Flexbox](https://codepen.io/jade-silhouette/pen/VwepKeo)

```css
html {
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 20px;
  place-self: center;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  min-width: 280px;
  max-width: 800px;
  justify-content: start;
  align-content: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 180px;
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>Link A</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>Link B</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>Link C</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>Link D</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>Link E</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

Here are some of many Stack Overflow threads that I referenced prior to posting:

- [How to create centered CSS grid with equal width columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437980/how-to-create-centered-css-grid-with-equal-width-columns)
- [CSS grid equal size columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747349/css-grid-equal-size-columns)

Comment: justify-content: center; on the nav in your first snippet?

Comment: Adding ```justify-content: center``` to the ```nav``` for the first snippet creates a seemingly random grid gap on the left side of the nav.

Comment: don't forget that you have a max-width applied, reduce the screen size and you will see the effect of justify-content:center

Comment: The first snippet's wrapping works as-is - my goal for it is to center the grid in the viewport (like in the second snippet). After the first snippet, there are some fixes I tried to make this happen - but they either convert the grid into a column (using the ```display:``` property) or ruin the wrapping (using the ```grid-[...]``` properties).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 180px);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  max-width: 800px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  outline:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Link A</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Link B</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Link C</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Link D</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Link E</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```